# Width of a radio buttons grid in a fieldset controlgroup jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, grid, width

I have a form containing two grids with raio buttons and trying to alin it to the width of the the header and other elements. Also I will appreciate any good sources, where I can learn about styling with jquery mobile. Using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery mobile 1.3.1

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk4bz/

```
<div data-role='page' id='bookingPage'>
        <div data-role='header' id='hBooking' class='hBooking'
            data-nobackbtn=true>
            <h1>Booking</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role='content' id='bookingContent' class='bookingContent'>

            <form id="bookingForm">


                <div id="select">
                    <select name="selectOrder" id="selectOrder"
                        data-native-menu="false">
                        <option value='choose'>Auftrag auswählen</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>

                <div id='timeRadios' class='timeRadios'>
                    <fieldset id="hours" class="ui-grid-b" data-type="horizontal"
                        data-role="controlgroup">
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-1"
                                value="1" /> <label for="radio-choice-1">1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-2"
                                value="2" /> <label for="radio-choice-2">2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-3"
                                value="3" /> <label for="radio-choice-3">3</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-4"
                                value="4" /> <label for="radio-choice-4">4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-5"
                                value="5" /> <label for="radio-choice-5">5</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-6"
                                value="6" /> <label for="radio-choice-6">6</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-7"
                                value="7" /> <label for="radio-choice-7">7</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                 <input
                                type="radio" name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-8" value="8" />
                            <label for="radio-choice-8">8</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b">
                             <input type="radio"
                                name="radio-choice-b" id="radio-choice-9" value="9" /> <label
                                for="radio-choice-9">9</label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="minutes" class="ui-grid-b" data-type="horizontal"
                        data-role="controlgroup">
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-d" id="radio-choice-15"
                                value="15"> <label for="radio-choice-15">15</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-d" id="radio-choice-30"
                                value="30"> <label for="radio-choice-30">30</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-d" id="radio-choice-45"
                                value="45"> <label for="radio-choice-45">45</label>

                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="bookingSubmit" type="submit" value="Buchen" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div data-role='footer' id='fBooking' class='fBooking'></div>
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    width:100%;
}
.ui-radio {
    width:100%;
}
```

**EDIT** When i remove the data-role="controlgroup" from the fieldset element everything is ok. But the radiobutton don't get then the  data-type="horizontal".

**EDIT2** Found the way to solve it. Removed the class="ui-grid-b" from the fieldset element and added a div with this class inside the fieldset wrapping the grid. Hier is the working example. http://jsfiddle.net/Nk4bz/1/

Comment: Trying to align how? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I want the grid to be the same size as the header and other elements of the form.

Comment: I think the issue is that jQuery mobile is doing the styling for you and you, and for that reason, you don't have a clear picture of what is going on . This isn't really an answer, but I think it might be interesting to you. This is how I would make this in basic form. Maybe it will help?  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/3RNsT/ Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but i hope there is also a way to overide only the the width and let jquery mobile do the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove the class="ui-grid-b" from the fieldset element and add a div with this class inside the fieldset wrapping the grid. Like This:

```
<fieldset id="minutes" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup">
<div class="ui-grid-b">
```

Hier is the working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk4bz/1/